# Using parallel controller with high concurrency

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

When I use the parallel controller to test 20K concurrency, the CPU usage of the stress tester is close to 100%, and the number of threads cannot reach the set value. Is there any way to reduce the resource usage of the parallel controller?
Ps:10 8Core 16G Agent used (2K Threads / per) , 1 Controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that kicking off 20k threads is a valid use case for the parallel controller.

Whatever. Parallel Controller just bypasses JMeter's limitation regarding inability to kick off extra threads i.e. for simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests. So parallel controller doesn't have "resources", it uses JMeter's resources pool.

So just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and it's maximum you can do about it.

If you still cannot conduct the required load using one machine you will have to calculate how many machines of similar hardware specifications you need and go for [Distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)